# How to model Azure Cosmos DB?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, data-modeling, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a Third Party APIs that backup Microsoft 365 data. I want to audit the results of backup processes on Azure Cosmos DB (SQL API).

We have backup jobs that will backup specific data.

The structure data for each backup job:

```
{
   "backup_job_id": "xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxx",
   "backup_job_name": "Exchange Backup Job",
   "schedulePolicy": {
        "type": "Daily",
        "dailyType": "Everyday",
        "dailyTime": "08:37:00"
    }
}
```

Every time the backup job runs, a new session is created and it will have the result of the backup job.
The structure data for each backup job session:

```
{
   "backup_job_id": "xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxx",
   "backup_job_session_id": "xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxx",
   "backup_job_session_status": "Success",
    "backup_items":[
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "User 1",
            "email": "user1@organization.onmicrosoft.com",
            "backup_status": "Success",
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "User 2",
            "email": "user2@organization.onmicrosoft.com",
            "backup_status": "Failed",
        },
        ......
        ......
        ......
        {
            "id": "10000",
            "name": "User 10000",
            "email": "user10000@organization.onmicrosoft.com",
            "backup_status": "Failed",
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I model the structure of Azure Cosmos DB (SQL API) for this data?
There isn't any updates queries on our database, It's almost just creating and reading.

I've read this article [Data modeling in Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/modeling-data) but still very confused about what is the best way to do that. I'm not sure if I need to embed backup_items inside backup job session as backup_items might reach 10000 items and the document might reach more than 2M size.

Comment: David's answer is correct. If you're new to modeling for Cosmos DB this link has a bunch of good resources. The video is a great place to start. https://gist.github.com/markjbrown/114179b3d530abe0eaa25fb9ac54b609

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really, how you model (and partition) your data is up to you, and there's no single "right" answer to this. However, you've already answered part of it yourself: in your example, you created an *unbounded array* situation, where the number of `backup_items` could grow to any number (and exceed maximum document size). And once you exceed that size, your model, and app, are effectively broken.

The solution to that specific problem is to store your unbounded-growth data as separate documents, with a common reference id matching the id of the session document (along with whatever additional data you care to store in each of those documents, based on your specific query patterns).